# Why iPhone don't receive push notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I really don't know where is the problem. 
I am using library ApnsPHP to sending Push notifications. I also tried other scripts, but that also not working.

I generate push certificates with this tutorial (http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/CertificateCreation) and also put them to apple developer website.
I get right token from iphone which i put into sample_push.php

I have Macbook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2010 with Mac OS Lion.

```
vojta:~/dev/www/application$ php sample_push.php 
Fri, 13 Apr 2012 16:23:24 +0200 ApnsPHP[6478]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Fri, 13 Apr 2012 16:23:32 +0200 ApnsPHP[6478]: INFO: Connected to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195.
Fri, 13 Apr 2012 16:23:32 +0200 ApnsPHP[6478]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue.
Fri, 13 Apr 2012 16:23:32 +0200 ApnsPHP[6478]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: Message-Badge-3] (1/3): 109 bytes.
Fri, 13 Apr 2012 16:23:33 +0200 ApnsPHP[6478]: INFO: Disconnected.
```

**If I execute "php sample_push.php" I will get no error, but also I not received any push notification on my iPhone.**

Source sample_push.php:

```
// Using Autoload all classes are loaded on-demand
require_once 'ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';

// Instanciate a new ApnsPHP_Push object
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
    ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
    'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem'
);

// Set the Root Certificate Autority to verify the Apple remote peer
$push->setRootCertificationAuthority('entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');

// Connect to the Apple Push Notification Service
$push->connect();

// Instantiate a new Message with a single recipient

$message = new ApnsPHP_Message('xxxx'); // i put my token here

// Set a custom identifier. To get back this identifier use the getCustomIdentifier() method
// over a ApnsPHP_Message object retrieved with the getErrors() message.
$message->setCustomIdentifier("Message-Badge-3");

// Set badge icon to "3"
//$message->setBadge(3);

// Set a simple welcome text
$message->setText('Hello APNs-enabled device!');

// Play the default sound
$message->setSound();

// Set the expiry value to 30 seconds
$message->setExpiry(30);

// Add the message to the message queue
$push->add($message);

// Send all messages in the message queue
$push->send();

// Disconnect from the Apple Push Notification Service
$push->disconnect();

// Examine the error message container
$aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();
if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
    var_dump($aErrorQueue);
}
```

I was also trying much more simple script (also not working)

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;


// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I really don't know what to do. Please help me someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.
It was because XCode signed app with iOS Team Provision Profile. After I deleted this profile,   push notifications started to work.

Comment: I remove all provision profile but still no response. Any idea ?

Comment: @SyedOsama, I came across the same issue. Did u find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Jacobian, Yes I solved this issue. 1) Check your .pem file have a RSA Private key ?

Comment: @SyedOsama, I fixed the issue....repeated the process of production certificate creation and it fixed...I messed something while generating push certificate previously...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When sending a push notification to apple, it returns you a status code. What is the status code you are receiving? Are you getting a 0 back?

```
Status codes
0   No errors encountered
1   Processing error
2   Missing device token
3   Missing topic
4   Missing payload
5   Invalid token size
6   Invalid topic size
7   Invalid payload size
8   Invalid token
255 None (unknown)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the php scripts using function stream_socket_client, which don't give me any answer. What do you using on server-side? I really looking for something, which I can also debug....

Comment: Fri, 06 Sep 2013 13:50:26 +0200 ApnsPHP[4632]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195...
Fri, 06 Sep 2013 13:50:27 +0200 ApnsPHP[4632]: INFO: Connected to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195.
Fri, 06 Sep 2013 13:50:27 +0200 ApnsPHP[4632]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue.
Fri, 06 Sep 2013 13:50:27 +0200 ApnsPHP[4632]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: unset] (1/3): 55 bytes.
Fri, 06 Sep 2013 13:50:28 +0200 ApnsPHP[4632]: INFO: Disconnected. I received this message and I have same issue.